# Prove that $ϕ ◦ ϕ = ϕ^2 = Id_{\Bbb C}$ (the identity map on C) if and only if $e^{iθ} \bar c + c = 0$.

Tags: complex-analysis, functions

Consider the isometry $ϕ : \Bbb C → \Bbb C$ with equation $ϕ(z) = e^
{iθ} \bar z + c$ where $θ ∈ \Bbb R$ and $c ∈ \Bbb C$. Prove
that $ϕ ◦ ϕ = ϕ^2 = Id_{\Bbb C}$ (the identity map on C) if and only if $e^{iθ} \bar c + c = 0$.

So far I have found that $ϕ ◦ ϕ (z)= e^{iθ}\bar c +z$. This is where I am stuck. I need to show that $ϕ ◦ ϕ (z)= e^{iθ}\bar c +z = Id_{\Bbb C}$ which I think means to show  $ϕ ◦ ϕ (z)= e^{iθ}\bar c +z = z$. For that to be true, $e^{iθ}\bar c =0$ must be true. How do I get from this to $e^{iθ} \bar c + c = 0$? Secondly, how do I find $ϕ^2$? That notation is unfamiliar to me.

Comment: $\phi^2$ is an alternative notation for $\phi\circ\phi$.

Comment: @MichaelAlbanese Ah ok. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know how you got $\phi^2(z)=e^{i\theta}\bar c+z$, but:

$$\phi\circ \phi(z)=\phi(e^{i\theta}\bar z+c)=e^{i\theta}\overline{e^{i\theta}\bar z+c}+c=e^{i\theta}(e^{-i\theta}z+\bar c)+c=z+e^{i\theta}\bar c+c$$

Comment: Ah I see. I forgot to add c under the composition. What about the reverse implication?

Comment: @Nid, $z+e^{i\theta}\bar c+c = \phi^2(z) = z\iff e^{i\theta}\bar c+c = 0$